# Share content FROM Facebook, not to it

Tags: unity, unity-networking, facebook

Regarding Unity 2018.x:

The Facebook SDK provides a way to get log-in information from a user's FB account, and allows information or an image from an app to be shared TO Facebook. Is it possible to link / access / reference or in any  other way make use of a specific image on Facebook within my Unity app?

Ideally, I would like to be able to access the image upon target recognition and, even better, store the image for subsequent display within the app. Finally, even more ideally ideally, this would not be the FB profile picture.

All suggestions and links welcome.

Comment: Have you checked questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756453/how-to-get-users-profile-picture-with-facebooks-unity-sdk) ?

Comment: Here and on the Unity docs/SDK... but I suspect I must be using the wrong vocabulary... as what I am finding is lots of info on sharing to, but not sharing from. @TomTsagk

Comment: The link I shared explains how to get the profile picture, maybe with a similar way you can get other pics as well? Getting just the profile picture is a good start though.